# Replacing column names when text varies slightly

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I often receive data csv files where the column titles are full of html junk––say:

```
"Do you like to VOTE _-<span style="font-size:16px;">in accordance with
your feelings&nbsp;</span>"
```

This is a pain to deal with, so I'll replace the junk with something manageable:

```
data = data.rename(columns={'Do you like to VOTE _-<span style="font-size:16px;">in accordance with your feelings&nbsp;</span>':'VOTE'})
```

The problem is that that the '_' character in the junk is not constant: sometimes it's an empty space, sometimes it's a question mark, etc. This means I have to manually specify the character, which defeats the whole purpose.

So, my question is, is it possible to specify a wildcard character that I can put in place of the underscore to allow for all possible cases? I understand that there's likely a regex method for this, but I wonder if I'm missing something more basic, as this looks like it should be a straightforward thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `re` module and substitute with a regular expression

```
import re

f = lambda x: re.sub(r'.*VOTE.*', 'VOTE', x)

df.rename(columns=f, inplace=True)
```

Or you can use the `str.replace` method on the `columns` object

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'.*VOTE.*', 'VOTE')
```

Comment: Thank you! Two actionable and very straightforward solutions here––exactly what I'd hoped for!